# only group titles showing in iOS settings bundle child pane

Tags: ios, ios7, settings.bundle

I'm about to make a settings for graphical stuff in a separate .plist. I have linked it from the Root.plist, but only the device only shows the group titles. Because i can't upload the images I paste the code here.

```
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Graphics</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Background Settings</string>
     </dict>
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Moving background</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>moveEnabled</string>
        <key>Default Value</key>
        <true/>
     </dict>
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Display Nebulas</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>nebulasEnabled</string>
        <key>Default Value</key>
        <true/>
     </dict>
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Display Stars</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>starsEnabled</string>
        <key>Default Value</key>
        <true/>
     </dict>
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Explosion Settings</string>
     </dict>
  </array>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

This is the part, where only titles shows, and this is how I linked it:

```
     <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Graphic Settings</string>
        <key>File</key>
        <string>Graphics</string>
    </dict>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure none of the elements in the PreferenceSpecifiers's array are missing a "required" key/value pair.

You can find Apple's reference for every shema element [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I had the same issue, it worked for me!